# Combining (OR) arbitrary regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, optimization

**tl;dr** Is there a way to OR/combine arbitrary regexes into a single regex (for matching, not capturing) in Java?

---

In my application I receive two lists from the user:

1. list of regular expressions
2. list of strings

and I need to output a list of the strings in (2) that were not matched by any of the regular expressions in (1).

I have the obvious naive implementation in place (iterate over all strings in (2); for each string iterate over all patterns in (1); if no pattern match the string add it to the list that will be returned) but I was wondering if it was possible to combine all patterns into a single one and let the regex compiler exploit optimization opportunities.

The obvious way to OR-combine regexes is obviously `(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)|...|(regexN)` but I'm pretty sure this is not the correct thing to do considering that I have no control over the individual regexes (e.g. they could contain all manners of back/forward references). I was therefore wondering if you can suggest a better way to combine arbitrary regexes in java.

---

note: it's only implied by the above, but I'll make it explicit: I'm only matching against the string - I don't need to use the output of the capturing groups.

Comment: Does one regex match only part of the string or does it match the entire string?

Comment: @Tomalak the regexes provided by the user should be allowed to match parts of the strings in (2) - in particular, in the naive implementation I use `Matcher.find()` to see if there's at least a match

Comment: And what makes you think that `regex1|regex2|regex3` produces wrong results? Can you construct a situation in which it would?

Comment: Without parentheses `regex1|regex2` for `regex1=A|B` and `regex2=C|D` produces `A|B|C|D` and that's clearly wrong.

Comment: Is it? If regex 1 is `A|B` and regex 2 is `C|D`, then the resulting regex matches any string that contains either of these four patterns. Looks right to me.

Comment: With parentheses (regex1)|(regex2) and for regex1=something and regex2=(something_else)\1 we get (something)|((somethingelse)\1) and that's wrong because the backref will refer to (something) instead of (somethingelse)

Comment: @Tomalak you're right. But the second case with backrefs applies also to regex1|regex2|...

Comment: I see. Yes, with back-references you are permanently out of luck. Self-referencing expressions cannot be combined.

Comment: Simplest solution might be to use a regexp parser to renumber backrefs... It's probably less difficult than it may sound, regexp syntax is pretty simple after all. Just count the groups and detect and fix the backrefs as you go through the combined pattern string.

Comment: @Tomalak some engines provide `(?|...|...|...)` where groups are counted from `1` for every single alternative... but I don't think Java does, unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Some regex engines (e.g. PCRE) have the construct `(?|...)`. It's like a non-capturing group, but has the nice feature that in every alternation groups are counted from the same initial value. This would probably immediately solve your problem. So if switching the language for this task is an option for you, that should do the trick.

[**edit:** In fact, it will still cause problems with clashing *named* capturing groups. In fact, the pattern won't even compile, since group names cannot be reused.]

Otherwise you will have to manipulate the input patterns. hyde suggested renumbering the backreferences, but I think there is a simpler option: making all groups named groups. You can assure yourself that the names are unique.

So basically, for every input pattern you create a unique identifier (e.g. increment an ID). Then the trickiest part is finding capturing groups in the pattern. You won't be able to do this with a regex. You will have to parse the pattern yourself. Here are some thoughts on what to look out for if you are simply iterating through the pattern string:

- Take note when you enter and leave a character class, because inside character classes parentheses are literal characters.
- Maybe the trickiest part: ignore all opening parentheses that are followed by `?:`, `?=`, `?!`, `?<=`, `?<!`, `?>`. In addition there are the option setting parentheses: `(?idmsuxU-idmsuxU)` or `(?idmsux-idmsux:somePatternHere)` which also capture nothing (of course there could be any subset of those options and they could be in any order - the `-` is also optional).
- Now you should be left only with opening parentheses that are either a normal capturing group or a named on: `(?<name>`. The easiest thing might be to treat them all the same - that is, having both a number and a name (where the name equals the number if it was not set). Then you rewrite all of those with something like `(?<uniqueIdentifier-md5hashOfName>` (the hyphen cannot be actually part of the name, you will just have your incremented number followed by the hash - since the hash is of fixed length there won't be any duplicates; pretty much at least). Make sure to remember which number and name the group originally had.
- Whenever you encounter a backslash there are three options:

  1. The next character is a number. You have a numbered backreference. Replace all those numbers with `k<name>` where `name` is the new group name you generated for the group.
  2. The next characters are `k<...>`. Again replace this with the corresponding new name.
  3. The next character is anything else. Skip it. That handles escaping of parentheses and escaping of backslashes at the same time.
- I think Java might allow forward references. In that case you need two passes. Take care of renaming all groups first. Then change all the references.

Once you have done this on every input pattern, you can safely combine all of them with `|`. Any other feature than backreferences should not cause problems with this approach. At least not as long as your patterns are valid. Of course, if you have inputs `a(b` and `c)d` then you have a problem. But you will have that always if you don't check that the patterns can be compiled on their own.

I hope this gave you a pointer in the right direction.